# Sharing domains with 2 different sites

Tags: django, subdomain, linode

I have a a pre-existing square-space blog with a domain hosted by square-space and I wish to share the domain name with a new django application that is hosted on linode, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In principle, yes.

A domain (e.g. `example.com`) is essentially a container of hosts|[sub]domains each of which may point to other hosts|[sub]domains until ultimately names e.g. `blog.example.com` are resolved to some IP address.

One, common and simple approach is that you would defined e.g. `blog.your-domain.com` to point to the square-space blog while another `www.your-domain.com` to point to the Django app running on Linode.

Another, common but more complex approach is that you would run an HTTPS reverse-proxy (possibly on Linode too) that receives requests directed to your domain and routes these either to your square-space blog or your Django app. This approach supports more routing complexity.